# deploying on Goerli with hardhat error insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost

Tags: smartcontracts, hardhat

Many people with the same error couldn't find a working solution.
It used to work on a local Ganache but I need to move over to goerli. But it doesn't work.

Deploy.js

```
async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

  console.log("Account balance:", (await deployer.getBalance()).toString());

  const Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("SLCAVotes");
  const contract = await Contract.deploy();

  console.log("Contract address:", contract.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

I have 0.2 goerli eth in my deployer account. The console.log confirms that + I checked on etherscan.
config file

```
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "goerli",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
    },
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
    },
    goerli: {
      url: process.env.ENDPOINT_URL,
      accounts: [process.env.DEPLOYER_KEY]
    }
  },
  solidity: {
    version: '0.8.11',
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
  paths: {
    sources: "./src/contracts",
    artifacts: "./src/abis"
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 40000
  }
}
```

I dont't know if this is enough information for you guys to help fix the issue. Please ask for anything you need.

Comment: does this log `console.log("Account balance:", (await deployer.getBalance()).toString())` "0.2" ether

Comment: it logs:"Deploying contracts with the account: 0x(my address)
Account balance: 200000000000000000" @Yilmaz

Comment: @Yilmaz I could really use your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now!

I changed my deploy script to this one I found on OpenZeppelin.

```
// scripts/deploy.js
async function main () {
  // We get the contract to deploy
  const Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory('SLCAVotes');
  console.log('Deploying Contract...');
  const contract = await Contract.deploy();
  await contract.deployed();
  console.log('Contract deployed to:', contract.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```